# PostgreSql+Spring:Trying to initialize a database with a SQL file but failing because of user auth

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, pgadmin

I am just starting out with PostgreSQL and I am using pgadmin4.I have tried to find some answers around here but couldn't find anything similar.
My java application.properties file contains the following lines

```
jdbc.url = jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/paper
jdbc.username = paper
jdbc.password = paper
```

my db-init.sql file which I use to create a database and add data to it contains the following lines

```
CREATE USER paper WITH PASSWORD paper;
CREATE DATABASE paper;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE paper to paper;
```

I have already created a default user that I had to when installing pgadmin. So this sql file should create another one no? Anyways the issue is this. When I am starting the jetty server I am getting this issue all the time

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "paper"
```

Why am I receiving this error? How can I fix it?

**L.E** added stacktrace

```
2020-09-29 00:08:26 WARN  HikariConfig:851 - Paper pool - using dataSourceClassName and ignoring jdbcUrl.
2020-09-29 00:08:26 WARN  HikariConfig:876 - Paper pool - maxLifetime is less than 30000ms, setting to default 1800000ms.
2020-09-29 00:08:26 INFO  HikariDataSource:71 - Paper pool - Starting...
2020-09-29 00:08:29 ERROR HikariPool:542 - Paper pool - Exception during pool initialization.
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "paper"
    at org.postgresql.Driver$ConnectThread.getResult(Driver.java:409)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:267)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:677)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:228)
    at org.postgresql.ds.common.BaseDataSource.getConnection(BaseDataSource.java:98)
    at org.postgresql.ds.common.BaseDataSource.getConnection(BaseDataSource.java:83)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:356)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:199)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:444)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:515)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:112)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.<init>(HikariDataSource.java:72)
    at com.example.paper.util.DataSourceFactory.createDataSource(DataSourceFactory.java:66)
    at com.example.paper.SpringConfiguration.dataSource(SpringConfiguration.java:46)
```

Comment: Can you paste the whole stacktrace here? Not clear which part of the code is giving this error, as jdbc.url is not a standard spring parameter.

Comment: @Boris i added part of the stacktrace, is this enough?

Comment: ok, now I see you have some pool called Paper. Can you show its definition? This should be some **@Configuration** class.

Comment: @Boris i can't find that class name in my project

Comment: That's not a class. "Paper" should be the name of the pool, so try to find this as text somewhere in the project.

Comment: @Boris i was able to make it work by running each query manually in the database. But i am curious where are the Pools usually declared in a project? where should i search for them? In the pom.xml? application .properties? the project has over 100 classes and it is hard to search for without knowing where to.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222205/discussion-between-boris-and-helloapp).